# set window title for mintty

Tags: vim, cygwin, mintty

With vim running on cygwin, I would like to automatically set the window title on the active buffer name.

I wrote this:

```
function! SetMinttyTitle()
    silent !clear
    execute "!" . "echo -ne '\\e]0;". @% . "\\a' 2>&1 > /dev/null"
endfunction

au BufNewFile,BufEnter,BufRead * call SetMinttyTitle()
```

Unfortunately It doesn't work as expected. I didn't find the way to get rid of this message

`"Press ENTER or type command to continue"`

How can I run my command on the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual answer is to use `system()` instead; it doesn't echo the output, but instead returns it.
But that won't work in your case, as you need the output to be printed to your terminal. Temporarily resetting `'shellredir'` may work:

```
set shellredir=
call system("clear; echo -ne '\\e]0;". @% . "\\a' 2>&1 > /dev/null")
set shellredir=>
```

But Vim actually has that functionality built-in, see `:help 'titlestring'`

Comment: I tried to use system in my function but it doesn't work

Comment: Ah right, because you need the output to go to the terminal. Doesn't `'titlestring'` work for you, as per my edit?

Comment: I didn't know `:set title`. You found the solution I was looking for. Thanks